# Clearing notifications from any of the activities in my android app

Tags: android

Suppose there are 2 activities in my app named Act1 and Act 2. Now, Act1, when closes, sends a  status notification, which invokes Act2. Using Act2, I can clear that notification. Now suppose that user doesn't clicks on the notification and invokes Act1 again, the notification doesn't gets cleared. I want that to happen. How could I do that?

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: hey, I found my solution.. :)
used cancelAll() method... :P

Comment: please post your solution here

Answer (score 5):

Using `android.app.NotificationManager` you can clear the notification by notification id.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
```

Comment: yeah..used cancelAll() to clear all the notifications..
Thanks neways.. :)